# How to consume WCF soap web service(net tcp binding only) in node.js

Tags: node.js, .net, wcf, node-modules

I have legacy WCF service which is hosted only using NetTcpBinding. I want to call the service in node js. is there any package or library which I can use?

Here is my WCF service configuration:

```
<wsdl:service name="Spedizioni_Avanzato_Out">
<wsdl:port name="NetTcpBinding_Spedizioni_Avanzato_Out" binding="tns:NetTcpBinding_Spedizioni_Avanzato_Out">
<soap12:address location="net.tcp://servername/SgaNetServiceInterop/Spedizioni_Avanzato_Out"/>
<wsa10:EndpointReference>
<wsa10:Address>
net.tcp://servername/SgaNetServiceInterop/Spedizioni_Avanzato_Out
</wsa10:Address>
</wsa10:EndpointReference>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no JS libraries to invoke the WCF service created by NetTcpBinding. It is very complicated. The following are some JS libraries that can call WCF, but none of them supports NetTcpBinding.
https://github.com/yaronn/wcf.js
https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap
The simpler way is to have WCF expose other service endpoints, such as WebHttpBinding. This allows you to create Restful style services. We can construct HTTP requests to call the service directly.